# hacer una consulta .find con varios ids con mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

En este caso tengo un modelo llamado admin_messages, y hago una consulta para traer todos los documentos (mensajes) que recibió el administrador y efectivamente los trae:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "5fde73caddb03670401f1357",
      "names": "juan",
      "lastname": "osorio",
      "phone": 3003214598,
      "product_id": "5fdd5c96da5a433f240825bf",
      "user_id": "5fd81f97cf35a95ab44a658d",
      "userMessage": "me interesa el tesla",
      "timeStamp": "2020-12-19T21:42:34.537Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fde73e5ddb03670401f1358",
      "names": "Juan",
      "lastname": "Osorio",
      "phone": 3003314587,
      "product_id": "5fdd5a58da5a433f240825bc",
      "user_id": "5fd81f97cf35a95ab44a658d",
      "userMessage": "Me interesa el audi",
      "timeStamp": "2020-12-19T21:43:01.398Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
```

yo recorro ese array de objetos y extraigo la propiedad  product_id (el id del producto en el cual el cliente esta interesado) y ahora del modelo productInfo quiero traer los dos productos

el problema es que solo me trae uno cuando lo muestro en las vistas, escribí así la consulta

```
   const allproduct_info =  await productInfo.find({_id: { $in: i.product_id} }).populate('image');`
```

y esta es la consulta completa:

```
ctrl.validateSuperAdmin = async(req, res, next)=>{
    const role = req.user.role;
    if(role === "superAdmin"){
        const all_messages = await admin_messages.find();
        res.send(all_messages);
        if(all_messages){
            for(i of all_messages){
                const allproduct_info =  await productInfo.find({_id: { $in: i.product_id} }).populate('image');
                res.render('../views/profile', {all_messages: all_messages, allproduct_info: allproduct_info});
                console.log(allproduct_info);
            }
            
        }
        
    }else{
        next();
    }
}
```

Esa consulta especifica me genera este error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client a pesar de que por lo menos arraja un resultado.

Sospecho que puede ser el formato de  i.product_id que son strings pero no sabría que fromato es el correcto si ese es el caso.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: el error especifica que se esta estableciendo una cabecera a la peticion(un headers) pero este se esta estableciendo después de que la petición fue echa y devuelta, revisa tus middlewares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas mandando `res.send` y `res.render` en la misma operación.

```javascript
    ctrl.validateSuperAdmin = async(req, res, next)=>{
        const role = req.user.role;
        if(role === "superAdmin"){
            const all_messages = await admin_messages.find();
            //Tu error esta aqui. 
            res.send(all_messages);
            //Si necesitas que la operación continúe debes omitir la linea anterior, que
            //por tu lógica parece ser lo que quieres. 
            if(all_messages){
                for(i of all_messages){
                    const allproduct_info =  await productInfo.find({_id: { $in: i.product_id} }).populate('image');
                    //Este es el problema de fondo. Se vuelve a mandar la cabecera 
                    // y te retorna el error. 
                    res.render('../views/profile', {all_messages: all_messages, allproduct_info: allproduct_info});
                    console.log(allproduct_info);
                }
                
            }
            
        }else{
            next();
        }
    }
```

Aun asi tienes un error en tu consulta. `$in` requiere un arreglo y tu estas pasando cada vez un solo id. En cada iteración vuelves a sobrescribir `allproduct_info`.

Para solucionar esto puedes hacer lo siguiente. :

```js
if (all_messages) {
  //Obtenemos un arreglo con los datos que nos interesan. 
  let todosMisIds = all_messages.map(x => x.product_id)
  const allproduct_info = await productInfo
    .find({
      _id: {
        $in: todosMisIds
      }
    })
    .populate('image');


  console.log(allproduct_info);
  //Te recomiendo uses return para evitar los errores de dobles headers
  return res.render('../views/profile', {
    all_messages: all_messages,
    allproduct_info: allproduct_info
  });
}
```

Editando..